# Reload previous page's JavaScript on mobile

Tags: javascript, css, mobile

I'm testing a template where each page has an `opacity` set to `0` and gets it set to `1` on page load with an event listener so that it appears to fade-in.

The issue I have is that when I hit "back" on mobile devices (namely iPhone 5) the JS won't execute, leaving the page with its 0 opacity.

I guess that the way it's done is to save bandwidth, but isn't there a way to force the browser to execute its JS even when hitting "back"?

Basic example of the code:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  someelement.style.opacity = '1';
});
```

Comment: Could you show us the code?

Comment: Which onload event are you using, for example.

Comment: Have you tried using timers?

Comment: Updated with a basic example. Timers won't fire as the JS is simply not executed again. It's also important to note that it's not an error with my JS, rather a specific behavior on mobile devices.

Comment: what happens if users have javascript disabled?

Comment: @serakfalcon There is a `no-js` class which adds an `opacity:1` to concerned elements.

Comment: I just had this problem today and found the answer in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24046/the-safari-back-button-problem

Answer (score 1):

I think I've found the best solution, coming from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12294511/3002125):

```
function Reload() {
  try {
    var headElement = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    if (headElement && headElement.innerHTML)
      headElement.innerHTML += " ";
  } catch (e) {}
}

if ((/iphone|ipod|ipad.*os 5/gi).test(navigator.appVersion)) {
  window.onpageshow = function(evt) {
    if (evt.persisted) {
      document.body.style.display = "none";
      location.reload();
    }
  }
}
```

This works perfectly. Other solutions didn't worked or showed some inconstancies for me. See [documentation for the onpageshow event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn298753.aspx)