# Safari back button doesn't reload page when used

Tags: javascript, safari

This issue -was- solved in older versions of Safari ([The Safari Back Button Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24046/the-safari-back-button-problem)). Although running the latest Safari (9.0.1), none of the solutions listed on the previous answer work anymore. Does anyone have a solution to "refresh/reload" the page when the back button on safari is used?

This -was- a way to detect if the page was accessed using the back-button. Although doesn't work in the version of Safari I'm using.

```
<body onunload="">
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Other answers bind things to window.onpageshow, but this is the only version that works for me: once your page is in a final state that you don't want to outlive a redirect, you can just bind the pageshow event and then check for the "persisted" property being true to determine if you should reload it.

```
window.addEventListener("pageshow", function(evt){
        if(evt.persisted){
        setTimeout(function(){
            window.location.reload();
        },10);
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: This is gold. We had problems where a mini cart was not updating in Safari and noticed that Amazon and other large sites trigger a page reload to solve the problem in Safari, something probably like this.

Comment: What might be useful as well is adding `document.body.innerHTML = '';` after the reload call to hide the old content artifacts

Comment: Details why this works can be found under the keyword  **bfcache** (e.g. via [this blog post](https://web.dev/bfcache/)). You can also hook in some code to tidy up in the prior page, instead of doing a full reload, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68606072/3991164) to avoid unnecessary load.

Comment: I use this to reconnect my websocket! +1

Comment: What does `persisted` mean in this case?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PageTransitionEvent/persisted
Basically if the state of the page is cached or not. I thiiiiiink if you didn't check, triggering reload from the pageshow event would cause an infinite loop.

Comment: More context: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/pageshow_event