# Alternative Javascript Method for PerformanceNavigation (Cross-browser Compatible)

Tags: javascript, performance, firefox, cross-browser, compatibility

I have semi-successfully implemented the following Javascript, but am having some difficulties achieving cross-browser compatibility (specifically in Firefox) with `window.performance.navigation`, since it has since been deprecated.

Here's what I've implemented, so far:

```
window.addEventListener("load",function(event){
    var historyTraversal=event.persisted||
    (typeof window.performance!=="undefined"&&
    window.performance.navigation.type===2);
    if(historyTraversal){
        window.history.back();
    }
});
```

Any alternative ways to formatting this?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/navigation), `Performance.navigation` is deprecated because it's marked as such in the [Navigation Timing Level 2 specification](https://w3c.github.io/navigation-timing/#obsolete). As recommended on the specs, [`PerformanceNavigationTiming`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceNavigationTiming) should be used instead: this is compatible with all the latest major browsers.

The property you're looking for is now available [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceNavigation/type), and you can query it as `var perfEntries = performance.getEntriesByType("back_forward");`.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it doesn't work in Safari.

This does (see [Safari back button doesn't reload page when used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33860241/safari-back-button-doesnt-reload-page-when-used)):

```
window.addEventListener("pageshow", function(evt){
    if(evt.persisted){
    setTimeout(function(){
        window.location.reload();
    },10);
}
}, false);
```